# Date Format Conversion - Requesting Optimization

Tags: scala

I have written this code which converts any `date as string` matching the defined date formats to the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. But I was thinking if this code can be further optimized.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.{DateTimeFormatter, DateTimeFormatterBuilder}
 def convertDate(strDate: String): String = {
    if (Option(strDate).isEmpty) ""
    else{
      val f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MMMM dd"))
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"))
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd"))
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMddyyyy"))
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd"))
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MMM dd"))
        .toFormatter

      val parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(isNull(strDate), f)
      val f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
      val newDate = parsedDate.format(f2)
      newDate
    }
  }
```

Please let me know if this can be further optimized / lines of codes can be decreased.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it works it might be better suited for a code review.

Anyhow, at least 2 observations:

- Your `Option.isEmpty` check seems suspicious, as it would return false if `strDate` is empty. I personally find `Option(strDate).getOrElse("").isEmpty` a bit verbose so tend to use `StringUtils.isBlank` from the Apache Commons project.
- `DateTimeFormatter` should be thread-safe so could be created outside of your function, compared to the pre-Java8 date formatters where that would have caused some issues.